# Android sqlite order by com case

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Preciso ordenar uma consulta como o exemplo abaixo, onde, o texto procurado é 'un', ele tras primeiro os itens que iniciam com 'un'. Eh isso mesmo que preciso, ordenar a saida da query, de forma que os itens que começam com o texto sejam os primeiros do resultado, mas sem eliminar os demais.

Utilizando esta resposta do StackOverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588817/1997073

Criei uma query no SQLite assim:

```
SELECT ProDescricao FROM ProdutosDB
where ProDescricao like '%un%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ProDescricao like 'un %'    THEN 0
                 WHEN ProDescricao like 'un%'     THEN 1
                 WHEN ProDescricao like '%un%' THEN 2
                 ELSE 3
END, ProDescricao;
```

Exemplo de saída:

```
28 |UNIAO SOLD 40-- 
29 |UNIAO SOLD 50-- 
30 |UNIAO SOLD 60-- 
35 |ADAPT UNIVERSAL 
44 |ADESIVO JUNTA 3M
48 |ALIC MINI 4,5 UN
34 |ACESS WC JUNIOR
```

Minha dúvida é, como fazer isso, com parâmetro? Chamando a consulta pelo Android usando a Query do SQLiteDatabase?

Note que o parâmetro seria sempre o mesmo:

```
SELECT ProDescricao FROM ProdutosDB
where ProDescricao like '%'+@busca+'%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ProDescricao like ''+@busca+' %'    THEN 0
                 WHEN ProDescricao like ''+@busca+'%'     THEN 1
                 WHEN ProDescricao like '%'+@busca+'%' THEN 2
                 ELSE 3
END, ProDescricao;
```

Seria algo assim? Está correto usar o Query do SQLiteDatabase ou devo usar alguma outra forma?

Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta porque pode usar o método `rawQuery()` assim:

```
String query = "SELECT ProDescricao FROM ProdutosDB " +
               "where ProDescricao like %?% " +
               "ORDER BY CASE WHEN ProDescricao like ?% THEN 0 " +
                             "WHEN ProDescricao like ?% THEN 1 " +
                             "WHEN ProDescricao like %?% THEN 2 " +
                             "ELSE 3 " + 
                        "END, ProDescricao";

String[] parametros = new String[] {"valor","valor","valor","valor"}

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, parametros);
```

Os parâmetros são indicados na *query* através do símbolo `?`
No segundo parâmetro de `rawQuery()` deve ser passado um `String[]` com os valores a serem atribuídos a cada um dos parâmetros.
<sub>***Nota:*** Parto do principio de que a *query* está correcta.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do @ramaral está quase correta, funciona com os parâmetros mas a classe não é compilada da forma postada, abaixo como ficou:

```
String query = "SELECT PD.ProCodigo, PD.ProDescricao, PD.ProP_Venda, ET.EstoqueQtdade, PD.ProQtdLote," +
                " TRIM(PD.ProCodigo||PD.ProDescricao) as ProCodDesc, ET.PermiteNegativo" +
                " FROM ProdutosDB PD, EstoqueDB ET " +
                " WHERE ET.EstoqueCodigo = PD.ProCodigo AND PD.ProDescricao LIKE ? " +
                " ORDER BY CASE WHEN PD.ProDescricao like ? THEN 0 " +
                              " WHEN PD.ProDescricao like ? THEN 1 " +
                              " WHEN PD.ProDescricao like ? THEN 2" +
                         " ELSE 3 END, "+ ( ordenarPorCodigo ?  "PD.ProCodigo;" : "PD.ProDescricao;");

String[] parametros = new String[]{"%"+busca+"%", busca+"%", busca+" %", "%"+busca+"%"};
Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, parametros);
```

Os simbolos '%' adicionados diretamente às queries causaram erros, quando feito append nos parâmetros deu certo.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934890/1997073

Comment: De facto a forma como eu postei não funciona porque o `?` é substituído pelo valor entre plicas ou seja ficaria assim `%'valor'%` o que não é *SQL* válido.